# What is the best way to deal with a homepage url change

Tags: url, referrer

The url for my homepage has changed. What is the best way to announce at the previous location that it has moved to the new location (so that search engines -- Google -- also take notice)?

Comment: Has the _domain_ changed? Or you want users to land on another URL on the same domain (ie. the homepage URL has changed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to do a 301 Redirect (301 meaning permanent as opposed to 302 temporary). This will forward on all traffic to the new location automatically. Search engines will take note of the 301 response and mark the homepage as moved to the new location.

Comment: Thanks. Since I don't have server-side access I guess I have to follow the advice here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13694/301-redirect-html-pages